# Full duplex communication using two USB headsets

Tags: usb, sound, alsa, microphone, jack

I have two USB headset and I'm trying to do a two way(Full duplex) communication between them.

`$ aplay -l
card 1: headset [Sennheiser USB headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: C320M [Plantronics C320-M], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

According to the jackd man page, this `jackd -d alsa -P hw:1,0 -C hw:2,0`
should do the job.

[image]

Jackd shows two capture devices, however the communication is only one way (from Card-2's Mic to Card-1's headphones).

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: [How can I use multiple soundcards with JACK?](http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/multiple_devices.html)

Comment: The problem with that is, it's not helping me get two way communication. Only one way is working